# Is there any chance to get a loan back from someone in another country? (Loanee is in Ireland, Lender in Netherlands)

Tags: european-union, ireland, netherlands

Lets say someone form another country loans a small amount of money (400 euro) in The Netherlands (A Dutch person lends money to someone from Ireland). Signing a Dutch loan contract (in English) stating to pay back withing 3 days, and taking a photocopy of the loanee with his/her passport in his/her hand, and a photo of his/her passport. Loanee acknowledges loan via e-mail, SMS and on video (phone camera). Loanee goes back to his country and ignores subsequent requests for the return of the payment. Is there anything the Dutch person can do to get his/her money back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the European Small Claims Procedure.

> The European Small Claims Procedure is available to litigants as an alternative to the procedures existing under the laws of the Member States. A judgment given in the European Small Claims Procedure is recognized and enforceable in another Member State without the need for a declaration of enforceability and without any possibility of opposing its recognition.
>
> Standard forms have been drawn up for the Small Claims procedure and are available here in all languages.

https://e-justice.europa.eu/content_small_claims-42-en.do

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Sue under Dutch law, and then apply to the Irish courts to enforce the judgement of the Dutch court.  This will be pretty much rubber stamped.