# What are legal ways to get a persons address (Person living in Ireland, I'm living in The Netherlands)?

Tags: european-union, small-claims-court, ireland, netherlands, borrowing

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/is-there-any-chance-to-get-a-loan-back-from-someone-in-another-country-loanee).

I filed for a [European small claims procedure](https://e-justice.europa.eu/content_small_claims-42-en.do) but the only address I had of that person, seems invalid. The people at the address in question claim they do not know of anyone by the name the letter was addressed to.

I tried getting the address in various ways:

- Contacting the DVLA because I have the other persons car (or at least a car they drove) registration on a photo
- Contacted my local free legal help / legal desk in my city (Juridisch Loket), they told me that maybe I could get the address through the Irish embassy, and starting a procedure without a valid address is not possible
- Contacting the Irish embassy in The Netherlands and request the address (because I have a photo of this persons passport and all the details)
- Contacting my local police to ask them if they would be able to give me the persons address, no results thus far

I am out of any ideas. I have a friend in UK that offered to help me, but when I discussed getting info from DVLA through him he said it's nearly impossible to get it done because the other person did not damage my friends car (and if it would be done he would need proof).

The person in question:

- I loaned 440 euro's from me and told me that the money will be paid back as soon as that person is home.
- To "Secure" myself I told him to hold his passport, let me take a photo of him visibly holding the passport, and take a close up of the passport,
- and I have a video recording of the person in question stating the loaned amount and that it will be paid back in 2 days.
- I also have a photo of the car the person drove.
- I have the persons gmail address where the person communicated with me and again admitted the loan and that the person will pay back the loan.
- I also have recorded voice conversations / calls where the person admits to the loan and that the person will pay it back.
- The number doesn't work anymore and e-mails are not answered anymore.
- Searching that person on Facebook or LinkedIn doesn't yield any matching results

The person in question is basically a stranger to me.

What are my (legal/lawful) options to get the address of the person in question so I can continue my European small claims procedure?

I hope there really are some options left, because in my mind it just baffles me that when a theft occurs and the person who did it is known, the person can get away with it..

Comment: Have you tried looking into property records?  Also, try looking up the plate on the car.  They are there for identification purposes.  Has the embassy or police gotten back to you?  Also, can you call the Irish Police? Private detectives?

Comment: The Dutch police replied to my inquiry that they have no results (and probably wouldn't be able to provide an address anyway for such a case, it would be different if that person would commit a "more serious" crime). I can try calling the Irish police, I hope they could help me. As for property records, I'll try look up how to, I didn't/don't know UK/Ireland has public property records. From what I see the property records only seem to be searchable by address, not by name, unfortunately.